# Recover the two-sided properties from a right-sided identity axiom and a left-sided inverse axiom

Tags: group-theory, axioms

At the end of this page: http://dogschool.tripod.com/housekeeping.html

It proves the left sided axioms using the right sided axioms. It then asks you at then end to prove the two-sided axioms using a right-sided identity axiom and a left-sided inverse axiom.

If we know only:

$e • a = a$

And

$a • a^{-1} = e$

How do we prove:

$a • e = a$

And

$a^{-1} • a = e$

Comment: Identity on the right and inverse on the left does not imply the two-sided versions, as can be verified by a small example.

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/433546/is-a-semigroup-g-with-left-identity-and-right-inverses-a-group

Comment: also: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/616577/intuition-proof-one-sided-group-definition-any-set-with-associativity-left