# Showing the binary operation $a * b = |a|b$ has a left identity and right inverse?

Tags: abstract-algebra, binary-operations

This is straight out of Fraleigh's book, "A first course in abstract algebra":

> Let $\mathbb{R}^*$ be the set of all real numbers except $0$. Define
>   $*$ on $\mathbb{R}^*$ by $a * b = |a|b.$

One of the problems is to show there is a left identity and right inverse, but I can't (obviously by design) get unique solutions out of the problem:

Suppose there's a left identity: $e * x = x \implies |e| = 1$, which gives us two possible identities. If I try to find a right identity, the solution is similar (though possibly different in sign): $e = \frac{x}{|x|}$.

For the right inverse ($x'$), the same problem comes up: $x * x' = e \implies |x|x' = e \implies x' = \frac{e}{|x|}$.

Comment: You mean left identity not right identity.  And yes, there are no reason why left identity is unique, when you don't have a right identity.

Comment: Are there any constraints on $\Bbb{R}^*$? Is it meant to be a particular kind of algebraic structure?

Comment: user10354138: Does that mean the question is "show there is /an/ identity element", even if there are technically multiple, and these do not form a group?

R. Burton: It's nothing but $\mathbb{R} - \{0\}$.

Comment: If it is not specified that $\Bbb{R}^*$ is any particular kind of structure (ex. a group, ring, etc.), then there is no reason that the identity or the inverse should be unique (unless otherwise specified).

Comment: Ah, so essentially the last question "Explain the significance of this exercise" probably refers to a lesson about the fact that the sheer existence of /an/ identity or inverse doesn't immediately give you a group structure, and one should be careful.

Comment: You can't have the "right identity" be $\frac{x}{|x|}$; because the right identity must work for **every** $x$, and here your $e$ changes depending on who $x$ is. So this doesn't work.

Comment: @NPerhaps you should also notice that you have to be careful: One may define group (with associativity given) in terms of unique two-sided identity and unique two-sided inverse, but in fact existence of a [left-identitiy and a left-inverse](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/616658/39174) are enough; likewise right-identity and right-inverse a enough. But as this exercise shows, mixing these restrictions (left-identity and right-inverse) fails