# A proposition which gives us an equivalence to the group definition.

Tags: group-theory

Let be $G$ a non-empty set and $*$ one law of composition inner. Suposse that $*$ is:

1) $\forall a, b, c \in G$ $a*(b*c)=(a*b)*c$;

2) $\exists e \in G$; $a*e=a=e*a$, $\forall a \in G$

3) $\forall a \in G $ $ \exists a' \in G$ ; $a'*a=e$. (opposite only the left )

Show that $G$ is group.

Comment: What is the question? Do you want to show that in a group left and right inverses are equivalent?

Comment: Yes!! The same thing happen with the $e$

Comment: Related (more general) question: [Right identity and Right inverse implies a group](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/65239/right-identity-and-right-inverse-implies-a-group)

Comment: And also these posts: [Any Set with Associativity, Left Identity, Left Inverse is a Group](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/537572/any-set-with-associativity-left-identity-left-inverse-is-a-group) AND

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Given $a$ pick $a'$ with $a'*a=e.$ Then using this $a'$ choose $a''$ for which $a''*a'=e.$ Now note that 
$$a*a'=e*(a*a')=(a''*a')*(a*a')=\\ a''*(a'*a)*a'=a''*e*a'=a''*a'=e.$$