# Does every element have a right inverse, when it has a left inverse?

Tags: group-theory

In a set endowed with an associative operation with a left identity and where every element has a left inverse, I was wondering, is every element bound to have a right inverse too? Or is there at least one set with a respective operation and such properties that at least one element doesn't have a right inverse? Clearly, an easy proof shows that if there is a right and a left inverse and the aforementioned properties hold, they have to be equal.

Note: This is merely a question of mine and not somehow part of homework.

Comment: The answer is yes, having a left identity and left inverses also implies right identity and right inverses (whereas left identity and right inverse is not enough). It is a good exercise to show this.

Comment: See also [this related question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/537572/4280)

Comment: @HennoBrandsma Both the question that mine has been marked as a duplicate of and the one you linked don't prove the **existence** of a right inverse (in my case, mutatis mutandis in their case) but instead take it for granted...

Comment: @Jason my linked one shows it is the same element in the body of the question. Did you read it? Once you show the same $e$ works for both sides, left inverses will give uniqueness, etc.

Comment: @HennoBrandsma Now I understand it better. You can prove existence of a right-inverse of an element because the element is the left-inverse of it...

Comment: @Jason You get some $e$ that is a left identity for all $a$. Then you show for all $a$ that $ae=a$ as well. But any such $e$ is unique because we have left inverses for all $a$. Now for any $a$ we have $a^{-1}$ with $a^{-1}a = e$. Then the post shows that also $aa^{-1} = e$.