# Does existence of a left or right inverse imply existence of inverses?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, inverse, monoid

Suppose $G$ is a set with a binary operation such that:

- (Associativity) For all $a, b, c \in G$, $(ab)c = a(bc)$.
- (Identity) There is $e \in G$ such that, for all $a \in G$, $ae = ea = a$.
- (Left inverse or right inverse) For all $a \in G$, $ba = e$ for some $b \in G$ **or (note the difference with and)** $ac = e$ for some $c \in G$.

Does this imply that every element $a \in G$ has an inverse, i.e. an element that is both a left and right inverse? That is, for all $a \in G$, is there $a’$ such that $aa’ = a’a = e$? In other words, is $G$ a group?

Comment: These questions basically answer yours: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/537572/any-set-with-associativity-left-identity-left-inverse-is-a-group and https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/65239/right-identity-and-right-inverse-implies-a-group

Comment: @GregMartin: These questions do not answer the Q in OP. Note the difference between "and" and "or".

Answer (score 29, accepted):

The answer is yes. Suppose $a$ has right inverse but not left inverse: $ab=e$. Then let $f=ba$. We have $ f^2= baba=ba=f$ and $f\ne e$. The element $f$ has a left or right inverse $c$. Suppose $fc=e$ , Then $f=fe=ffc=fc=e$, so $f=e$, a contradiction. If $cf =e$ then $f=ef=cff=cf=e$, again a contradiction.

Comment: I have a strong feeling of déjà vu. I think I have seen this strategy (namely, an idempotent element with a left or right inverse must be the identity element) used before in some *other* questions. Does anybody know any examples?

Comment: There is a similar proof of the statement that if a monoid is finite and $ab=1$ then $ba=1$. The point is that if $ba\ne 1$ then all elements $b^ka^k, k=1,2,...,$ are idempotents and if $b^ka^k=b^{k+m}a^{k+m}$ then $b^ma^m=1$, and so $a$ has a left inverse which then must be $b$.