# Do those 'groups' have a name?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, terminology, definition

Is there a name for 'groups' that only have a neutral element *on the right* and an inverse for each element *on the right* ?

If there is, does that name also hold for a neutral elt on the right and an inverse on the left ?

In any case, do those kind of 'groups' have special properties/are interesting to study ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, in the first case, they are called groups.  See [Right identity and Right inverse implies a group](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/65239/right-identity-and-right-inverse-implies-a-group) That is, the "only" is a priori, but it turns out in this case that the identity and inverses are $2$-sided.

(But for the case of having a right identity and left inverses, I do not know of a name or interesting properties. They need not be groups.)