# Confusion in notation, problem from Herstein's book.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, notation

> Let $G$ be a nonempty set closed under an associative product, which in
>   addition satisfies :
>
> A. There exists an $e$ in G such that $a⋅e=a$ for all $a∈G$.
>
> B. Given $a∈G$, there exists an element $y(a)∈G$ such that $a⋅y(a)=e$.
>
> Prove that $G$ must be a group under this product.

This is a question from I N Herstein. It was already asked before. Here is the solution

https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1200617/581242

> Let, $ab=e\land bc=e\tag {1}$ for some $b,c\in G$. And, $ae=a\tag{2}$
>   From $(2)$, $$eae=ea\implies(ab)a(bc)=ea\implies
>  ((ab)(ab))c=ea\implies ec=ea\tag{3}$$
>
> Similarly, $$ae=a\implies a(bc)=a\implies (ab)c=a\implies
>  ec=a\tag{4}$$
>
> $(3)$ and $(4)$ implies, $$ea=a$$
>
> Also from $(3)$ and $(1)$, $$(bab)(bca)=e\implies
>  b((ab)(bc)a)=e\implies ba=e$$

I don't understand the notation used in first line. What does $$ab=e\land bc=e$$ mean?

Comment: The $\wedge$ means "and."

Comment: A fun fact, symbol $\land$ is also used for minimum and wedge product. In this case, it's logical "and" though.

Comment: As a tip for the future, you can do a search on the internet for, say, "\land meaning LaTeX" and find the answer quickly. And when you don't know the code for a symbol, you can find it on one of Wikipedia's lists of mathematical symbols or use Detexify to find the TeX code as an alternate starting point.

Comment: @MarkS. Thank you for the advice:)

Comment: @Jakobian: in Boolean algebra, and/or are indeed the minimum/maximum operators. There is also a close connection with $\cap/\cup$.

Comment: @YvesDaoust In Stochastic processes, we usually write minimum like that. That's what I was relating to. I know that in Boolean algebra $\lor$ and $\land$ operators create an ordering as well, and in that ordering, $\land$ can be interpreted as the minimum. I didn't think about that, but it gives me a whole different view on why is $\land$ used as minimum in stochastic processes. Thank you.

Comment: Bit of advice: Unless you are doing symbolic logic and have to, do not follow that solution's poster by using $\wedge$ and $\vee$ for and/or when writing proofs. Apart from causing the problem you have just illustrated yourself, it is simply unnecessary. Some people get carried away when they get handy with symbols.

Answer (score 1):

The symbol $\wedge$ means “and”. So, the first line means “$ab=e$ and $bc=e$”.

Answer (score 1):

In [logic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_logic_symbols), $\land$ means "and" and $\lor$ means "or."