# Altering the identity axiom in group theory

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, proof-explanation

I had a question in one of my group theory exercises, it goes as follows.

> Suppose that in the definition of a group $G$, the condition that $\exists$ an element $e$ with the property 
> $$ae = ea = a \,\,\,\forall\, a \in G$$ 
> is replaced by $ae = a \,\,\,\forall\, a \in G$. Then show that $ea = a \,\,\,\forall\, a \in G.$

The solution that was provided for this problem used cancellation property $$ab = ac \implies b= c$$

> Solution:
> We're given that $$ae = a$$
> Pre-multiplying $a^{-1}$ on both sides we get,
> $$ a^{-1}(ae) = a^{-1}a$$
> $$ (a^{-1}a)e = a^{-1}a$$
> Post multiplying both sides by a
> $$ (a^{-1}a)ea = a^{-1}aa$$
> $$ \therefore eea = ea$$
> By the cancellation property we get
> $$ ea = a$$

But this cancellation property is proved using the very condition i.e. $ea = a \,\,\,\forall\, a \in G$ that we're trying to prove here.

So am I correct in assuming that the cancellation property as stated above cannot be used? Also is there an alternate approach to solve this question?

Comment: Are you also assuming the existence of a right inverse?  If so, [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/65239/right-identity-and-right-inverse-in-a-semigroup-imply-it-is-a-group#:~:text=Note%20here%20ec%3Dc,the%20uniqueness%20of%20inverse%20functions.) is a duplicate.

Comment: As lulu says: You will, of course, also need the part of the definition about "inverse".  Since you have not told us what that is, how can we answer?

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange. If you want us to verify whether the solution provided is correct, I think you would need to provide us with more detail. What does the solution actually say? In the post that lulu links to, I posted an [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/65239/right-identity-and-right-inverse-in-a-semigroup-imply-it-is-a-group/4661831#4661831) which is taken from Lang's *Algebra*. I think it is the quickest proof.

Comment: The question didn't mention anything specific about inverses. So I guess we could assume that the axiom for inverses is not altered. Also, I will update the question with the solution that was provided.

Comment: Fix $a$, and let $b$ be such that $ab=ba=e$. Then $a = ae = a(ba) = (ab)a = ea$. If you only know that $G$ has a right identity and right inverses, then see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1199489/742),

Comment: If the proof of left cancellation used that $ex=x$ for all $x$ (quite likely) then the argument is indeed circular. It is also unnecessarily convoluted. If you assume (as they clearly do) two-sided inverses, then simply start with $ea$, replace $e$ with $aa^{-1}$, and associate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming only $ae = a$ for any $a\in G$

Then

$$ea = (aa^{-1})a = a(a^{-1}a) = ae = a $$

Note that for this argument you need both sided inverses