# Proving that if $ab=e$ then $ba=e$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Suppose that instead of the property $ab=ba=e$ a group G has the condition that for every element $a$ there exists an element $b$, such that $ab=e$. Prove that $ba=e$. Is the following a valid proof?

Since $ab=e$ then under the condition of the group there exists an element $k$ such that $bk=e$ for some $k$ in the group.

Now $bk=e$ so $abk=ae$ therefore $(ab)k=a$ and finally $ek=a$ and $k=a$.

Is this a valid proof?

Comment: Seems good to me

Comment: Wait a moment, if a group $G$ satisfies the condition:
$$\forall a,b\in G \Rightarrow ab = \mathrm{id}_G,$$
then it is forced to be the trivial group
$$G = \{\mathrm{id}_G\}.$$

Which condition are you exactly imposing on your group?

Comment: I assume the first sentence in this post is a misinterpretation of the problem to be solved.

Comment: @GiovanniDeGaetano Yes I corrected it. Thank you for pointing that out...

Comment: good to go ....

Comment: See also: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/65239/right-identity-and-right-inverse-implies-a-group/

Answer (score 3):

I assume that you mean if for SOME $a,b$ (not every) $ab = e$ then $ba = e$.
Your proof  is valid, but you could write it much easier without playing with $k$. $$ab = e \Rightarrow  bab = b.$$ If you already know the cancellation law, then we are done.  Otherwise you may continue by writing $baba = ba$, so that $(ba)^2 =ba$. Just note that the only idempotent in a group is $e$.

Comment: The cancellation law is a consequence of the existence of unique inverses (as is the fact that $e$ is the only idempotent). Without expanding the proofs of one of those statements, this is just hiding the desired statement rather than proving it.

Comment: @MiloBrandt Cancellation law  has nothing to do with "uniqueness". Ones you have a right (left) inverse then you have the right (left) cancellation law. In this problem we have $G$ is a group, so by definition we have right and left inverses.

Comment: I think after: $$ab = e \Rightarrow  bab = b.$$ We can probably just conclude by associativity $(ba)b=b$, and since the identity is unique then $ba=e$ from there?

Comment: @StefanT. You should be careful here. As Milo mentioned, using uniqueness is not allowed here unless you prove it. Here you can write $(ba)b = eb$ and use the right cancellation.