# Proof of brauer's lemma, $eRe$ being a division ring.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, noncommutative-algebra, division-ring

On page 1 of this [article](http://www.thebookshelf.auckland.ac.nz/docs/NZJMaths/nzjmaths022/nzjmaths022-01-010.pdf), the author proves the following claim:

> Brauer's Lemma: Let $K$ be a minimal left ideal of a ring $R$, with $K^2 \not= 0$. Then $K=Re$ where $e^2=e \in R$, and $eRe$ is a division ring.

**What I do not understand** is why $eRe$ is a division ring. They showed  for  $b\not=0$ *in* $eRe$ exists $(ere)b=e$ (where $e$ is the identity in this ring). This shows left invertibility, but not right.

What am I missing?

Comment: It follows from associativity and the identity axioms.  Just as how you may define a group with lefthanded axioms only and it is equivalent to the ordinary definition.

Comment: Sorry, I tried to work from the axioms but did not get anywhere, do you mind writing it out?

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/65239/right-identity-and-right-inverse-implies-a-group

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested, then $ere\neq 0$ has a left inverse too, which consequently you will show is equal to $b$, so that $ere$ and $b$ are mutually inverse.

Another way to do it is to show that $End_R(Re, Re)\cong eRe$, and if you're familiar with Schur's lemma, that makes it obvious $eRe$ is a division ring too.