# Surjectivity of right and left translations implies semigroup is in fact group

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, semigroups

I want to show a set of statements on a semigroup $G$ are equivalent.
The left and right translations are given by $l_g(h)=gh$ and $r_g(h)=hg$ respectively.

1. $G$ is a group
2. For all $g \in G$ both $l_g$ and $r_g$ are bijective
3. For all $g \in G$ $r_g$ is surjective and there exists an $f\in G$ s.t. $l_f$ is surjective

The implications from 1. to 2. and 2. to 3. I managed. But I'm struggling with proving 3. implies 1. I think I only need to show the existence of the neutral and inverse elements, as $G$ is by assumption a semigroup and thereby closed.

A neutral element for each element must be in $G$ as $r_g$ is surjective so in particular $\forall g\in G: \exists e\in G$ s.t. $g=r_g(e)$. How can I show that this e is the same for all $g$?

I still don't see how I can show the **inverse** elements lie in $G$

Comment: I’m assuming you do not allow the empty semigroup?

Comment: You’ve shown that for each $g\in G$ there exists $e\in G$, *which may depend on $g$*, with $eg=g$. You have *not* shown that the same $e$ works for every $G$, so you have not shown that $G$ has a neutral element.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin edited to reflect your comment, thank you

Comment: @ArturoMagidin even though it's not explicitly stated, I think they implicitly don't allow the empty semigroup. Good point though, I didn't even think of that counterexample.

Comment: A lot of authors disallow the empty semigroup; that would satisfy 2, but neither 1 nor 3.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin the exercise asks us to **prove** the statements, so I believe it was an oversight on part of the author.

Comment: Or the author may simply have defined “semigroup” so as to exclude the empty set. That’s fairly common.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(From the statement, it seems clear that the particular author does not consider the empty set to be a semigroup; this does not matter for the implication $3\Rightarrow1$, as the statement of 3 implies $G$ is nonempty, but it affects the proof of $2\Rightarrow 3$.)

Let $e_f$ be such that $e_ff=f$. For every $g\in G$, there exists $x$ such that $fx=g$; therefore, for every $g\in G$ we have
$$e_fg = e_f(fx) = (e_ff)x = fx = g.$$
Thus, $e_f$ is a left identity for $G$.

And for every $g\in G$ there exists $x$ such that $xg=e_f$. Thus, $G$ has a left identity and every element has a left inverse. These two conditions are known to guarantee that a semigroup is in fact a group.

Comment: For future readers: Here is a proof of the fact that these two conditions guarantee a semigroup is a group. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=E1WNqKSDGio

Comment: @RubenKruepper: The problem has been solved [in this site](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/65239/right-identity-and-right-inverse-implies-a-group); that one is for right identity and right inverse, but the solution is the same *mutatis mutandis*.