# In a semigroup does left identity and right inverse imply a group?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, semigroups

Say we have a set $ G $ with the properties

1. $ G $ is closed under some opperation $ \circ  $
2. $ G $  is associative under $ \circ  $
3. There exists an element $ e\in G $ such that for every $ g \in G $ we have
   \begin{align*}
     e\circ g=g .
   \end{align*}
4. For every $ g\in G $ there exists $ g^{-1}\in G $ such that
   \begin{align*}
     g\circ g^{-1}=e.
   \end{align*}
   Is it a group?

I have tried manipulating the expressions to get the standard definition of a group but to no success. I don't even know if it is true. I found this post [Right identity and Right inverse implies a group](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/65239/right-identity-and-right-inverse-implies-a-group), which shows something close, but not exactly what I want. Moreover, the top comment states

> In case you don't know: Right identity and Left inverse does not imply group.

and I wonder if left identity and right inverse do not imply a group. If anybody could give me some guidance I would greatly appreciate it.

Comment: Define $g\star h=h\cdot g$, and you can switch between a group $(G,\star)$ and the "opposite group" $(G,\cdot)$.

Comment: I'm convinced that this is a duplicate question but I can't seem to find it.

Comment: @ElliotG thank you for the comment. I can't seem to follow what you are getting at. Would you mind elaborating?

Comment: @Shaun I looked all over stackoverflow but I can't seem to find such a question. I also looked at literature but I wasn't able to find anything. If you do, please let me know and I will remove the post.

Comment: I'm just saying there won't be any meaningful difference between "right identity / left inverse" and "left identity / right inverse"

Comment: @ElliotG I see where you are getting at. Do you by any chance have any resources on whether it is a group when we have right identity & left inverse? The comment says it is not but I can't seem to find a counterexample.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simple example: let $S = \{a, b\}$ (where $a$ and $b$ are distinct) and define $x \cdot y = y$. Then $S$ is a semigroup with left identity $a$, and corresponding right inverse $x^{-1} = a$ (which is to say, the right inverse of an element $x \in S$ is $a$, regardless of whether $x = a$ or $x = b$).

Note that this left identity, and the corresponding right inverse, is not unique! We could just as easily have nominated the left identity to be $b$, and the right inverse would constantly be $b$ as well.