# An example of a semigroup where the following holds

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

I am looking for an example of a semigroup wher the right inverse and right identity holds but it is not a group.

Is there an example of such a semigroup- i was not able to prove that if the above condiion holds then it is a group..

Comment: A semigroup in which there is a right identity and every element has a right inverse is necessarily a group, so no such examples exist. See for example, [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/65239/right-identity-and-right-inverse-implies-a-group).